Unpacking a commit shows commit <number> which cat-file and log doesn't show
So for fun I've been learning a bit more about gits internals. I've noticed when I unpack commit objects they look like this: (With info redacted)
$ openssl zlib -d -in C:\Users\<project-folder>\.git\objects\b0\582816e2251e51dbf93f163fd037817fde8090
commit 302 tree 018cdc33104ac6363d540cb7289340c609ff5449
parent fda1b3f941b76710ca1418d22de097140d2d3202
author name <email> 1708350154 +0000
committer name <email> 1708502487 +0000

Message

That commit 302 is what I can't seem to find much about. The same commit printed with cat-file -p doesn't show that number
$ git cat-file -p b0582816e2251e51dbf93f163fd037817fde8090
tree 018cdc33104ac6363d540cb7289340c609ff5449
parent fda1b3f941b76710ca1418d22de097140d2d3202
author name <email> 1708350154 +0000
committer name <email> 1708502487 +0000

Message

Likewise git log doesn't either. So what is it?

Does it exist in git reflog?

@choroba Seems like a good guess, but not in the regular reflog. And I can't seem to find anything in the docs that would bring it up

See the object file format documentation, subsection Object Storage.

@j6t that is it exactly. No idea how I missed that but thank you!
